# Inno Setup: How do I see the output (translation) of the Inno Setup Preprocessor?

Tags: preprocessor, inno-setup

I have an Inno Setup script with preprocessor directives (`#define`s, `#if`s, etc.)

I want to run the Inno Setup preprocessor on my script and see the preprocessor's output (translation in Inno-Setup-speak). That is, I want to look at the result of the preprocessor which it normally feeds into the Inno Setup Compiler, where all the references to `{#something}` are changed into whatever `something` was defined as.

I look at the command line options (of `iscc.exe`) and `#pragma` directives and did not find what I'm looking for. I see that I can specify not to run the compiler (`#pragma -c- | /$c-`) but I did not find a way to look at the output of the preprocessor.

In short, how do I look at the output of the Inno Setup preprocessor?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When all else fails look for the answer yourself

Add the following line right at the end of the script.

This will generate a file `preprocessed.iss` with all macros expanded and `#define`s, `#if`s etc. processed.

```
#expr SaveToFile(AddBackslash(SourcePath) + "Preprocessed.iss")
```

Comment: I would recommend to add this line at the very end of the script, because `SaveTofile` outputs only the preprocessed part of the script up to the currently processed line.