# Function to add multiple source lines to Inno File section

Tags: inno-setup

Is there a function or preprocessor directive that can be used to add multiple lines to the Files section in Inno Setup?  For example, I have numerous occurrences of a pattern similar to the following:

```
[Files]
Source: "{#SrcPath}\Dir1\FileName.*"; DestDir: {#DstPath}\Dir1;   
Source: "{#SrcPath}\Dir2\FileName.*"; DestDir: {#DstPath}\Dir2;  
Source: "{#SrcPath}\Dir3\FileName\*"; DestDir: {#DstPath}\Dir3\FileName; Flags: recursesubdirs
```

And while I can just copy and paste the lines for each one, I was wondering if instead I could do something like this?

```
[Files]
AddFiles(FileName)
```

Unfortunately, I can't find any examples in the docs or online that illustrates how to do this.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a preprocessor macro (template) using the [`#define` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=define) like this:

```
#define FileTemplate(str FileName) \
  "Source: """ + SrcPath + "\Dir1\" + FileName + ".*""; DestDir: " + DstPath + "\Dir1;" + NewLine + \
  "Source: """ + SrcPath + "\Dir2\" + FileName + ".*""; DestDir: " + DstPath + "\Dir2;" + NewLine + \
  "Source: """ + SrcPath + "\Dir3\" + FileName + ".*""; DestDir: " + DstPath + "\Dir3; Flags: recursesubdirs"
```

And expand the template using the [`#emit` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=emit) like this:

```
#define SrcPath "C:\srcpath"
#define DstPath "{app}"

[Files]
#emit FileTemplate("FileName1")
#emit FileTemplate("FileName2")
```

If you get the [preprocessor to dump a preprocessed file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3328375/850848), you will see that the code produces this:

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\srcpath\Dir1\FileName1.*"; DestDir: {app}\Dir1;
Source: "C:\srcpath\Dir2\FileName1.*"; DestDir: {app}\Dir2;
Source: "C:\srcpath\Dir3\FileName1.*"; DestDir: {app}\Dir3; Flags: recursesubdirs
Source: "C:\srcpath\Dir1\FileName2.*"; DestDir: {app}\Dir1;
Source: "C:\srcpath\Dir2\FileName2.*"; DestDir: {app}\Dir2;
Source: "C:\srcpath\Dir3\FileName2.*"; DestDir: {app}\Dir3; Flags: recursesubdirs
```

---

*For `NewLine` [predefined preprocessor variable](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=predefinedvars), you need Inno Setup 6. See also [Emit new line in Inno Setup preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45999277/850848)*.

Comment: I had looked at the define directive, but couldn't get the syntax right.  Thanks for the insight.  The dump to a preprocessed file is very helpful for debugging as well.