# Emit new line in Inno Setup preprocessor

Tags: inno-setup

When using [Inno Setup preprocessor](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/) to generate a multi-line output, like for example in these answers of mine:

- [Inno Setup - Recurse sub directories without creating those same sub directories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36742636/850848)
- [Function to add multiple source lines to Inno File section](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40497860/850848)
- [Generating Inno Setup file flags programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40728147/850848)
- [Inno Setup: Dynamically add a component for all files in a folder and its subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45059158/850848)
- [Choose between source paths for all files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45969182/850848)

I always have to switch to the C-style string literals using [`#pragma parseroption` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=pragma), because with C-style string literals, I can use `\n`:

```
#pragma parseroption -p-

#define TwoLines "line1\nline2\n"

#pragma parseroption -p+
```

---

I haven't found any way to emit a new-line character in the default Pascal-style string literals.

In a real Pascal (Script) string, one can use `#13#10`. But that does not work in the preprocessor. Neither there's an equivalent of Pascal [`Chr` function](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/chr.html).

Is there any other way to emit a new line in the Pascal-style string literals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [`NewLine` macro](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=predefinedvars) available in Inno Setup 6.

---

If you are on an older version of Inno Setup, you can define the macro in your own script. It's defined as:

```
#pragma parseroption -p-
#define NewLine "\n"
#pragma parseroption -p+
```

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the source code of the Inno Setup Preprocessor:

https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/tree/master/Projects/ISPP

I think there is no other way than yours. The preprocessor is mainly based on a C tokenizer and the `parseroption -p` basically just enables/disables the support for escape sequences. But there is no implementation for parsing Pascal character literals like `#13#10`.

Comment: I arrived to the same conclusion when looking at the code. But I just could not believe that the default string type has such a limitation.