# Evaluate preprocessor macro on run time in Inno Setup Pascal Script

Tags: inno-setup

I'm using an Inno Setup #define directive to define all of the information about a software package in my installer and then other directives to extract portions of that string.  So for example, using the following, `PartNumber(Package1)` will return 05414.

```
#define Package1 "05414 - My Package"
#define PartNumber(str Package) Copy(Package, 1, 5)
```

I'm using this approach in scripts and code and it works fine.  However, I've got a situation where it would be convenient to programmatically generate the string and I'm having trouble getting it to work.  For example, I'd like to do something like the following.

```pascal
procedure Foo(Package: String);
var
  PartNumber: String;
begin
  PartNumber:= ExpandConstant(Format('{#PartNumber(%s)}', [Package]));
end;

procedure Bar();
begin
   Foo(ExpandConstant('{#Package1}')); 
end;
```

The `Package` argument to `Foo` is correct, but I get a compiler error saying

> [ISPP] No argument for format '%'".

It seems that it doesn't like the `#` in the string on the `PartNumber` line.  Even including a `#` in a normal string gives an "unterminated preprocessor directive" error, so I think it's interpreting the `#` as a precision specifier or something.

Is there a way to make it treat `#` as part of the text so that I can programmatically expand this constant?  If not, if there some other way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This cannot work.

The `PartNumber` is a [preprocessor function/macro](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=define). It's evaluated on compile time. It does not exist on run time.

---

You can, of course, implement an equivalent Pascal Script function:

```pascal
function PartNumberPascal(Package: string): string;
begin
  Result := Copy(Package, 1, 5);
end;

procedure Foo(Package: String);
var
  PartNumber: String;
begin
  PartNumber := PartNumberPascal(Package);
end;
```

---

What probably confuses you, is this call:

```pascal
Foo(ExpandConstant('{#Package1}'));
```

It may give you an impression that the [`ExpandConstant` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_expandconstant) expands the `Package1` preprocessor define.

It does not!

The `{#...}` syntax (contrary to the `{...}`) is not a [constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts). It's an [inline preprocessor directive call](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=directives), where, when no directive is explicitly specified, the [`emit`](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=emit) is implied. So the `{#Package1}` is the same as `{#emit Package1}`. And as every preprocessor construct, it's evaluated on compile time.

If you [add `SaveToFile` preprocessor function call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3328375/850848) to the end of the script:

```pascal
procedure Bar();
begin
  Foo(ExpandConstant('{#Package1}')); 
end;

#expr SaveToFile(AddBackslash(SourcePath) + "Preprocessed.iss")
```

And after compilation, check, what the `Preprocessed.iss` is like. You will see:

```pascal
procedure Bar();
begin
  Foo(ExpandConstant('05414 - My Package')); 
end;
```

The `Package1` is expanded to its value. But the `ExpandConstant` is still there, and hence it's totally useless! (there are no constants in the `'05414 - My Package'`)

This would have the same effect:

```pascal
procedure Bar();
begin
  Foo('{#Package1}'); 
end;
```

---

For a similar question, see:
[Evaluate a collection of data from preprocessor on run time in Inno Setup Pascal Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60971940/850848)

Comment: Great explanation as always Martin.  Thanks.