# How to use Inno Setup preprocessor directive in [Code] section?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I feel like this has got to be something simple I'm missing - in Inno Setup, if I have passed in a directive variable, how do I use it inside the `[Code]` section?

Say I pass in `/DMYVAR=1` to the Inno Setup engine.

In my .iss file I can have something like:

```
[Setup]
AppName=MyApp v{#MYVAR}
```

Down in my `[Code]` section I'd like to be able to use it like this:

```pascal
function IsVersionOne(param: String): boolean;
begin
    Result := {#MYVAR} == "1";
end;
```

This doesn't work :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Preprocessor does not care, where its directives are expanded.

So `{#name}` syntax ([inline preprocessor directive call](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=directives)) works everywhere, including Pascal Script.

Though, if you want to compare a `define` value as a string, you have to, of course, enclose it to quotes to make it a string. Also note that your `== "1"` syntax is wrong, Pascal uses single `=` and single quotes.

```pascal
function IsVersionOne(param: String): boolean;
begin
    Result := '{#MYVAR}' = '1';
end;

#expr SaveToFile(AddBackslash(SourcePath) + "Preprocessed.iss")
```

Run the compiler with `/DMYVAR=1`, and check the generated `Preprocessed.iss`. It will show:

```pascal
function IsVersionOne(param: String): boolean;
begin
    Result := '1' = '1';
end;
```

As the value is a number, you can, of course, use numerical comparison too:

```pascal
function IsVersionOne(param: String): boolean;
begin
    Result := {#MYVAR} = 1;
end;
```

---

For a related question with more detailed information, see [Evaluate preprocessor macro on run time in Inno Setup Pascal Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41070563/850848).

---

While the above answered your *literal question*, your `function` signature  actually suggests that you want to implement a [`Check` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck) to test a value of a compile-time directive, like:

```
[Files]
Source: "MYPROG.EXE"; DestDir: "{app}"; Check: IsVersionOne
```

That's an inefficient overkill.

Use a [preprocessor `#if` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=if) instead:

```
[Files]
#if MYVAR == "1"
Source: "MYPROG.EXE"; DestDir: "{app}"
#endif

#expr SaveToFile(AddBackslash(SourcePath) + "Preprocessed.iss")
```

If you run the compiler with `/DMYVAR=1`, `Preprocessed.iss` will show:

```
[Files]
Source: "MYPROG.EXE"; DestDir: "{app}"
```

If you run the compiler with a different value of `DMYVAR`, `Preprocessed.iss` will show:

```
[Files]
```

If you need the script to compile even without `/DMYVAR=` switch, define a default value at the top of the script, like:

```
#ifndef MYVAR
#define MYVAR "0"
#endif
```