# How to read a [Setup] parameter in the Pascal code?

Tags: inno-setup

How can I read a parameter set in the `[Setup]` section namely `Uninstallable` in the Pascal code?

The reason why I need to know if the package produced is uninstallable or not, is an information displayed on the ready page (the name of the package in the Add/Remove display of Windows). If the package is `Uninstallable=no` that information does not make sense so I should no show it on the ready page!

Thanks a lot for any hints!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`SetupSetting` preprocessor function](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=setupsetting) to emit the `Setup` section directive in other places of the script (`Code` or not):

```
[Setup]
Uninstallable=no
```

```pascal
[Code]
...
if '{#SetupSetting('Uninstallable')}' = 'yes' then ...
```

This results in:

```pascal
if 'no' = 'yes' then ...
```

Related question: [How to use Inno Setup preprocessor directive in [Code] section?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48914783/850848)

---

Though I actually find your solution better. But for type-safety and avoiding problems like case-sensitive comparison or quoted values, I'd do it like this:

```
#define Uninstallable false

[Setup]
Uninstallable={#Uninstallable ? "yes" : "no"}
```

```pascal
[Code]
...
if {#Uninstallable ? 'True' : 'False'} then ...
```

This results in more efficient:

```pascal
if False then ...
```

---

Or actually if you just want to skip whole block of code, do:

```
[Code]
...
#if Uninstallable
// Do something
#endif
```

This results in no code, when not "uninstallable", what is even more efficient and also reduces the installer size.

---

And then it is more common to just test for existence of the preprocessor define:

```
//#define Uninstallable
[Setup]
#ifndef Uninstallable
Uninstallable=no
#endif
```

```pascal
[Code]
...
#ifdef Uninstallable
// Do something
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

My 'problem' can be solved as follows:

```
#define uninstallable "no"
...
[Setup]
...
Uninstallable="{#uninstallable}"
...
[code]
...
if {#uninstallable} = 'yes' then ...
```

With this `uninstallable` is known in the pascal code. Not very elegant but possible. I still would like to know if parameters in `[Setup]` can be read from the pascal code?

Comment: This won't compile. Your are missing quotes. It should be `if '{#uninstallable}' = 'yes' then ...`. On the other hand the quotes in `"{#uninstallable}"` are not needed. You typically write `Uninstallable=no`, not `Uninstallable="no"` (although it is possible).