# How to set my own variable in [Setup] and read it from [Code]

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm trying to create a script in Inno Setup to pull files from a GitHub repository, extract it, and write it to a directory defined in the `[Setup]` section.

```
[Setup]
MyVariable={userappdata}\MetaQuotes\Terminal\{#MyAppName}
```

```pascal
[Code]
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  // Copy the selected files to the selected directory
  if not FileCopy(Output + '\file1.txt', MyVariable + '\file1.txt', False) then
  begin
    MsgBox('Failed to copy file1.txt to the selected directory.', mbError, MB_OK);
    Abort();
  end;
  if not FileCopy(Output + '\file2.txt', MyVariable + '\file2.txt', False) then
  begin
    MsgBox('Failed to copy file2.txt to the selected directory.', mbError, MB_OK);
    Abort();
  end;
end;
```

Obviously, this won't compile because `MyVariable` hasn't been defined in the Pascal script. Only, I'm not sure how to reference the value in `[Setup]`. Or am I going about this in the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can read the `[Setup]` section directives with [`SetupSetting` preprocessor function](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=setupsetting):
[How to read a [Setup] parameter in the Pascal code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73672934/850848)

But you cannot invent your own new directives.

---

But you can either:

- Use preprocessor variable using [`#define` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=define) (the way you already use it for `MyAppName`):

  ```
  #define MyVariable "{userappdata}\MetaQuotes\Terminal\" + MyAppName
  ```

  It does not matter where you place the `#define` as long as it it before you use the variable.

  Use it like this in the Pascal Script:

  ```pascal
  ExpandConstant('{#MyVariable}\file1.txt')
  ```

  The [`ExpandConstant`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_expandconstant) is to expand the `{userappdata}`.
- Use Pascal Script constant:

  ```pascal
  [Code]

  const 
    MyVariable = '{userappdata}\MetaQuotes\Terminal\{#MyAppName}';
  ```

  Use it like any other Pascal Script variable/constant.

  ```pascal
  ExpandConstant(MyVariable) + '\file1.txt'
  ```

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful. I just started working with Inno Setup today and the documentation hasn't been very helpful so far.