# How to check a value of [Setup] directive on runtime in a Inno Setup installer?

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

I need to determine the value of the `WizardStyle` setup directive for a conditional in my Pascal Script section. To do something like this:

```pascal
if WizardStyle = "Modern" then
begin
    // Code to run for "modern" style.
end
else if WizardStyle = "Classic" then
begin
    // Code to run for "classic" style.
end;
```

How can achieve this? This does not seem to work: `ExpandConstant('{WizardStyle}')`

I have read this, but I don't take things in clear about how to determine the value of this directive:

- [How to use Inno Setup preprocessor directive in [Code] section?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48914783/how-to-use-inno-setup-preprocessor-directive-in-code-section)
- [Evaluate preprocessor macro on run time in Inno Setup Pascal Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41070563/evaluate-preprocessor-macro-on-run-time-in-inno-setup-pascal-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your answer works, it actually makes little sense to check a compile time directive value on run-time. In your case the run-time check penalty is low, so it does not really matter. But in general, do check on compile-time.

For example:

```
#if LowerCase(SetupSetting("WizardStyle")) == "modern"
// Code to run for "modern" style
#else
// Code to run for "classic" style.
#endif
```

Another approach:

```
// Remove or comment out for the default "classic" style
#define UseModernWizardStyle
```

```
[Setup]
#ifdef UseModernWizardStyle
WizardStyle=modern
#endif
```

```
#ifdef UseModernWizardStyle
// Code to run for "modern" style.
#else
// Code to run for "classic" style
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found the solution in this doc:

- https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/topic_setupsetting.htm

With a usage example in the `[Code]` section of this other doc:

- https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=emit

So this is how one can do it to obtain the value:

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  WizardStyle: String;

begin
  WizardStyle := LowerCase('{#SetupSetting("WizardStyle")}'); // "modern" or "classic"

  if WizardStyle = 'modern' then
  begin
    // Code to run for "modern" style.
  end
  else if WizardStyle = 'classic' then
  begin
    // Code to run for "classic" style.
  end;

end;
```