# Using Inno Setup preprocessor variable value with quote/apostrophe in Pascal Script code

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

When I define a preprocessor string variable (using the ISPP) that contains a quote/apostrophe, there will be a compiler error when I use the function `ExpandConstant` in the `[Code]` section to read this string.

Here's an example `.iss` script for demonstrating/testing:

```pascal
#define _AppName "Uli's Program"

[Setup]

AppName={#_AppName}
AppVersion=1.2.3
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#_AppName}

[Code]

function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
begin
  MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{#_AppName}'),
         mbInformation,
         MB_OK);
  Result:=False;
end;
```

The exact compiler error message is:

> comma (',') expected.

**Update**

This works when the apostrophe is doubled. But now the captions of the wizard pages show the app name with a double apostrophe (because of `AppName={#_AppName}`).

A similar issue occurs when the `#define` is removed and the script is altered this way:

```pascal
[Setup]

AppName=Uli's Program
AppVersion=1.2.3
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#AppName}

[Code]

function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
begin
  MsgBox('{#SetupSetting("AppName")}'),
         mbInformation,
         MB_OK);
  Result:=False;
end;
```

Now the compiler error message is

> Assignment expected.

Comment: Double up the apostrophe.

Comment: Yes, that work's - but now the captions of the wizard pages show the app name with a double apostrophe (because of "AppName={#_AppName}").

Comment: It seems to me that you can't then: https://ww1.fileforums.com/showthread.php?p=416825. Others might say otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the macro to create an entry in [`CustomMessages` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=custommessagessection).

And then load the custom message in Pascal Script using [`CustomMessage` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_custommessage).

```pascal
#define _AppName "Uli's Program"

[CustomMessages]
MyAppName={#_AppName}

[Code]

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  MsgBox(CustomMessage('MyAppName'), mbInformation, MB_OK);
  Result := False;
end;
```

---

Another (rather hackish) way is to use [`StringChange` preprocessor function](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=stringchange) to double the quote in Pascal Script.

```pascal
#define _AppName "Uli's Program"

[Code]

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  MsgBox('{#StringChange(_AppName, "'", "''")}', mbInformation, MB_OK);
  Result := True;
end;
```

*Note that I do not use `ExpandConstant` to resolve the preprocessor variable/expression - It's nonsense. See [Evaluate preprocessor macro on run time in Inno Setup Pascal Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41070563/850848)*.

---

[image]