# TBitmapImage is rendered larger than its size on scaled display in Inno Setup 6

Tags: windows, image, installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

Just updated to latest Inno Setup v.6.0.3. But now I get white borders in my `TBitmapImage` image. The script below worked just fine with the older version 5.

So, what's seems to be wrong with the newer version and the script I have been using for years?

Please note that I have scaled my display about 125%.

```pascal
ExtractTemporaryFile(ExpandConstant( '{#BackgroundImage}' ));
BackgroundBitmapImage := TBitmapImage.Create(MainForm);
BackgroundBitmapImage.Left := 0;
BackgroundBitmapImage.Top := 50;
BackgroundBitmapImage.AutoSize := True;
BackgroundBitmapImage.Bitmap.LoadFromFile( ExpandConstant('{tmp}\{#BackgroundImage}')  );
BackgroundBitmapImage.Parent := MainForm;
```

[image]

Neither the exact size of the image fixed the problem.

```pascal
ExtractTemporaryFile(ExpandConstant( '{#BackgroundImage}' ));
BackgroundBitmapImage := TBitmapImage.Create(MainForm);
BackgroundBitmapImage.Left := 0;
BackgroundBitmapImage.Top := 50;
BackgroundBitmapImage.Width := 600;
BackgroundBitmapImage.Height := 500;
BackgroundBitmapImage.AutoSize := False;
BackgroundBitmapImage.Bitmap.LoadFromFile( ExpandConstant('{tmp}\{#BackgroundImage}')  );
BackgroundBitmapImage.Parent := MainForm;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The display, where your `MainForm` window is located, is scaled/zoomed.

When you set the `.Parent`, the control is rescaled to the target display. To prevent that, set the `.Parent` before (implicitly) setting the size.

```pascal
ExtractTemporaryFile('{#BackgroundImage}');
BackgroundBitmapImage := TBitmapImage.Create(MainForm);
BackgroundBitmapImage.Parent := MainForm;
BackgroundBitmapImage.Left := 0;
BackgroundBitmapImage.Top := 50;
BackgroundBitmapImage.AutoSize := True;
BackgroundBitmapImage.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(
  ExpandConstant('{tmp}\{#BackgroundImage}'));
```

---

*Note that there's no need to call `ExpandConstant` for `'{#BackgroundImage}'`, as it [does not contain any constant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41070563/850848).*