# How can I write the LanguageID into the Registry in Inno Setup?

Tags: registry, inno-setup

I have 3 languages, so I write this:

```
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Company\Office\Client"; ValueType: dword; ValueName: "LocaleID"; ValueData: "?"; Languages: en
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Company\Office\Client"; ValueType: dword; ValueName: "LocaleID"; ValueData: "?"; Languages: ru
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Company\Office4\Client"; ValueType: dword; ValueName: "LocaleID"; ValueData: "?"; Languages: ua
```

In the `ValueData` field I have to put the corresponding LanguageID (`$0419` for Russian, `$1058` for Ukrainian and `$0409` for English, etc). I could put those numbers manually, but I wonder if there's a way to extract the LanguageID from its name or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [preprocessor](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/) to generate `[Languages]` and `[Registry]` entries at the same time. The preprocessor has [`ReadIni` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=readini), which you can use to read the `LanguageID` from the `.isl` files.

```
#define AddLanguage(Name, File) \
  "[Languages]" + NewLine + \
  "Name: " + Name + "; MessagesFile: ""compiler:" + File + """" + NewLine + \
  "[Registry]" + NewLine + \
  "Root: HKLM; Subkey: ""SOFTWARE\Company\Office\Client""; ValueType: dword; " + \
    "ValueName: ""LocaleID""; " + \
    "ValueData: " + ReadIni(CompilerPath + File, "LangOptions", "LanguageID") + "; " + \
    "Languages: " + Name + NewLine

#emit AddLanguage("en", "Default.isl")
#emit AddLanguage("ru", "Languages\Russian.isl")
#emit AddLanguage("uk", "Languages\Ukrainian.isl")
```

That will generate a code like this (lines wrapping and empty lines added for readability):

```
[Languages]
Name: en; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Company\Office\Client"; ValueType: dword; \
  ValueName: "LocaleID"; ValueData: $0409; Languages: en

[Languages]
Name: ru; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Russian.isl"

[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Company\Office\Client"; ValueType: dword; \
  ValueName: "LocaleID"; ValueData: $0419; Languages: ru

[Languages]
Name: uk; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Ukrainian.isl"

[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Company\Office\Client"; ValueType: dword; \
  ValueName: "LocaleID"; ValueData: $0422; Languages: uk
```

---

*[Add `SaveToFile` to the end of the script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3328375/850848) to see the generated code.*